# how to filter a record in where clause in impala query using conditional statements

Tags: sql, where-clause, impala, sql-view

Below is the sample data for reference

table 1

```
col1  col2
cmpy1 dev
cmpy1 testing
cmpy1 support
cmpy2 dev
cmpy2 testing
cmpy2 support
cmpy3 dev
cmpy3 testing
cmpy3 support
```

I will create a view `table1_view` on top of `table1` in impala, the view should filter out the record like when `col1 = 'cmpy1'` and `col2` in 'dev', so rest of records should populate in view when i do `select * from table1_view`.

Could someone help me in applying filter condition in `where` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will create a view `table1_view` on top of `table1` in impala, the view should filter out the record like when `col1 = 'cmpy1'` and `col2` in 'dev'

Do you just want a `where` clause?

```
create view table1_view as
select col1, col2
from table1 
where not (col1 = 'cmpy1' and col2 = 'dev')
```

Comment: actually i need to skip this record only from view (col1 = 'cmpy1' and col2 = 'dev')

Comment: @HarishPadmanaban: yes, that's what the statement does. If you `select * from table1_view`, these row(s) will not show up.